# Init script & the green [ OK ]

Tags: php, fastcgi, daemon, shell-scripting, init.d

I am trying to install fast-cgi for nginx on an EC2 instance. I followed the steps explained [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample),  but that is meant for Debian and does not work out of the box for a red-hat based system. I modified the script a bit to look like -

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php-fcgi
# Required-Start:    $nginx
# Required-Stop:     $nginx
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts php over fcgi
# Description:       starts php over fcgi
### END INIT INFO

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

(( EUID )) && echo .You need to have root priviliges.. && exit 1
BIND=/tmp/php.socket
USER=nginx
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=15
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000

PHP_CGI=/usr/bin/php-cgi
PHP_CGI_NAME=`basename $PHP_CGI`
PHP_CGI_ARGS="- USER=$USER PATH=/usr/bin PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=$PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=$PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS $PHP_CGI -b $BIND"
RETVAL=0

start() {
      echo -n "Starting PHP FastCGI: "
      #ORIGINAL LINE
      #daemon $PHP_CGI --quiet --start --background --chuid "$USER" --exec /usr/bin/env -- $PHP_CGI_ARGS
      #MODIFIED LINE
      daemon --user=$USER $PHP_CGI -b $BIND&
      RETVAL=$?
      echo
      [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/php-fcgi
      #echo "$PHP_CGI_NAME."
}
stop() {
      echo -n "Stopping PHP FastCGI: "
      killall -q -w -u $USER $PHP_CGI
      RETVAL=$?
      echo "$PHP_CGI_NAME."
      rm /var/lock/subsys/php-fcgi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
      start
  ;;
    stop)
      stop
  ;;
    restart)
      stop
      start
  ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: php-fastcgi {start|stop|restart}"
      exit 1
  ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

The problem I have now is -

1. `service php-fcgi start` keeps the shell blocked. If I run `service php-fcgi start &` and then  `ps aux`, I see the php-cgi process running bound to the socket. I see the start command stop only when I execute `service php-fcgi stop`. How do I solve this blocking issue? I have tried adding an `&` at the end of the line spawning the daemon. But other scripts do not seem to be doing this. 
   This is the most complicated script I am attempting to modify yet :-(
2. How do I get the script to display the green `[ OK ]`? I checked scripts like httpd and saw that all they were doing was something as shown below. But I never see a green `[ OK ]` when I execute `php-fcgi`. I also discovered that putting `echo_success` with `functions` sourced displays the green `[ OK ]` but I do not see any other scripts in the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` executing `echo_success` or `echo_failure`. What have I got wrong?
3. Also, How do i specify `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` with `daemon`?

> ```
> echo
>       [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/
> ```

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the `daemon` line to:

   ```
   daemon --user $USER --pidfile=$PIDFILE "$PHP_CGI -b $BIND &> /dev/null &"
   ```

   `&> /dev/null` is equipvalent to `>/dev/null 2>&1`, means that
   redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.
2. If that doesn't show the `[ OK ]` flag, try this:

   ```
   if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
       echo $pid > $PIDFILE
       success "Starting php-cgi service"
   else
       failure "Starting php-cgi service"
   fi
   ```

   Take a look at the `success` function in the `/etc/init.d/functions`
   for more details.

   The `stop` function should change to:

   ```
   killproc -p $PIDFILE $PHP_CGI_NAME
   ```
3. Insert the `PHP_CGI_ARGS` as an environment variable to the `daemon` function:

   `daemon --user $USER --pidfile=$PIDFILE "env - $PHP_CGI_ARGS
   $PHP_CGI -b $BIND &> /dev/null &"`

Moreover, to make it start automatically at boot, you should change the init info to the Red Hat based style:

```
# chkconfig: 345 85 15
# description: Running php-cgi
# processname: php-cgi
# config: /etc/sysconfig/php-cgi
```

Comment: There should be an echo after the `success`, `failure` or `warning` functions, as in `success; echo "Good job!"`

Comment: As a side note, I can only print the `[ OK ]` message from `success` if I use `echo`, and I can't see how it should work otherwise after reading the code for `success`... But, there are pieces of code showing `success` messages without `echo` I have no idea how it could work, so if someone understands it, please to tell me

Answer (score 2):

So, you're on a redhat based system, and you want a version of PHP that comes with FPM (the best way to do cgi on PHP >= 5.3)?  Why don't you just install the packages from somewhere like IUS: http://iuscommunity.org/ , rather then trying to get a custom-built version working?  The repository will allow you to stay up to date a lot easier, and will generally make your life easy.

Once the repo is installed, this is all you'd need to do: `chkconfig php-fpm start; service php-fpm start`, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. While this will help me with the fast CGI, I would still like to know how to write init scripts. I tried reading a few, but am not able to replicate their behavior.